# How to create a nested hashmap with multiple datatypes in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to get the output something like this:

```
[
 {
   "index": 2,
   "range": true,
   "label": { 
              "Label1":"Value1",
              "Label2":"Value2"
            }
 }
]
```

combination of values with an integer boolean and map<string,string>

In Python we can do it simply with a list and a dictionary but how can I achieve this in Java?

Comment: what is the input type

Comment: so what holdes all these variables

Comment: Which question are you asking, how to create the lists and maps described, or how to convert them to JSON?

Comment: How to create lists and maps described

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure you're describing appears to be something like this:

```
List.of(Map.of(
    "index", 2,
    "range", true,
    "label", Map.of("Label1", "Value1", "Label2", "Value2")
))
```

which is a `List<Map<String, Object>>`